# Python: Error while using openai's whisper

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I get a Cannot find reference 'load_model' in 'whisper.py' and the errors when running my code looks like this. I'm not sure how to debug this or why I'm getting these errors as the entire project was passed on to me from the previous person.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Downloads\Project\Project\Speech to Text\Whisper.py", line 7, in <module>
    import whisper
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper.py", line 69, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import whisper


# Define the function to transcribe the audio file
def transcribe_audio_file():
    # Get the path to the selected audio file
    audio_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir=".",
        title="Select audio file",
        filetypes=(
            ("MP3 files", "*.mp3"),
            ("WAV files", "*.wav"),
            ("All files", "*.*")
        )
    )

    # Check if the user cancelled the file dialog
    if not audio_file_path:
        return

    # Get the selected model size
    selected_model = model_var.get()
    model_name = None
    if selected_model == "Tiny":
        model_name = "tiny"
    elif selected_model == "Base":
        model_name = "base"
    elif selected_model == "Small":
        model_name = "small"
    elif selected_model == "Medium":
        model_name = "medium"
    elif selected_model == "Large":
        model_name = "large"

    # Load the Whisper model
    model = whisper.load_model(model_name)

    # Transcribe the audio file
    result = model.transcribe(audio_file_path, fp16=False, language='English')

    # Update the GUI with the transcription
    transcription_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    transcription_text.insert(tk.END, result['text'])

    # Save the transcription to a file with the same name as the audio file
    output_file_path = os.path.splitext(audio_file_path)[0] + ".txt"
    with open(output_file_path, "w") as file:
        file.write(result['text'])

    # Show a message box indicating that the transcription was saved
    messagebox.showinfo("Transcription saved",
                        f"The transcription has been saved to file:\n{output_file_path}")

# Function to copy the transcription to clipboard


def copy_to_clipboard():
    transcription = transcription_text.get(1.0, tk.END)
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(transcription)


# Create the main window of the GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Audio Transcription App")

# Create a label and button for selecting the audio file
audio_file_label = tk.Label(root, text="Select an audio file to transcribe:")
audio_file_label.pack()

audio_file_button = tk.Button(
    root, text="Select file", command=transcribe_audio_file)
audio_file_button.pack()

# Create a label and radio buttons for selecting the model size
model_label = tk.Label(root, text="Select a model size:")
model_label.pack()

model_var = tk.StringVar()
model_var.set("Large")

tiny_radio = tk.Radiobutton(
    root, text="Tiny", variable=model_var, value="Tiny")
tiny_radio.pack()

base_radio = tk.Radiobutton(
    root, text="Base", variable=model_var, value="Base")
base_radio.pack()

small_radio = tk.Radiobutton(
    root, text="Small", variable=model_var, value="Small")
small_radio.pack()

medium_radio = tk.Radiobutton(
    root, text="Medium", variable=model_var, value="Medium")
medium_radio.pack()

large_radio = tk.Radiobutton(
    root, text="Large", variable=model_var, value="Large")
large_radio.pack()

# Create a label and text box for displaying the transcription
transcription_label = tk.Label(root, text="Transcription:")
transcription_label.pack()

transcription_text = tk.Text(root, height=10)
transcription_text.pack()

# Create a button to copy the transcription to clipboard
copy_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Copy to Clipboard",
                         command=copy_to_clipboard)
copy_button.pack()

# Start the main loop of the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

What error am I having? Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, never name your .py  files after libraries you're using! Secondly, the error message clearly tells you that problem is with importing "whisper" and it seems to be a path related problem judging from what that if statement in __init__.py is checking. Look into __init__.py inside whisper to see what exactly is going on.

https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/__init__.py

Comment: It seems like you have installed wrong module.  Install `whisper.ai` module instead of `whisper`.